# Different color of each row in DataFrame based on data in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

So what I'm trying to do is, based on content in column, set color for whole row ([view image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZZz1.png))

Example: If data in column Status is "Finished", then the color for that row is blue; for "Reading" the color is green etc.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter='|')

def colored_text():
    if df.loc[df['Status'] == 'Reading']:
        return 'color: green'
    else:
        return 'color: yellow'
    

df.style.applymap(colored_text)

print(df)
```

Output of this is only white-colored table.
I've also tried `df.style.apply(colored_text)` with the same result.

At that point I was lost, so I tried `df.style.set_properties(color="green")` instead of `.apply(colored_text)` and again, the output was the same white-colored table.

So now I'm not even sure if code in `def colored_text():` is correct or not

Comment: You have `print(df)` that's always going to give you plaintext console output... If you want to see the display of a pandas styler you'll need to be in a dynamic HTML environment like Jupyter Notebook or Google Colab, or export to an environment which supports styling like Excel, LaTeX, or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'status': ['Reading', 'Writing', 'Reading'], 'other col': range(3)})
n = len(df.columns)
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: red"]*n if x['status']== 'Reading' else ["background-color: white"]*n, axis = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. I got same output as always, color changes didn't apply. I guess that the problem is somewhere else ?

Comment: You can see that I produced the results. maybe your packages or python version differs.